# How to export crystalreport to pdf file by c# win app? (1 record per export to 1 file.)

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

How to export the crystal report to pdf file on win app by c#?

Now I can export all records to single pdf file.

I would like to export 1 record to 1 pdf file

and use some field on record is part of name file.

My code for export all records to single file as below.

```cs
private void exportPdf(DataSet  Xx)
{
    ReportClass rpt = new ReportClass ();
    rpt .SetDataSource(Xx);
    csrViewer.ReportSource = rpt ;

    rpt .ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, @"D:\exportPDF.pdf");
}
```

Comment: try to bind only one record to your dataset and use loop for processing each record.. rest of code is okay

Comment: Yes. It's work. Thank you so much.

Comment: You re welcome, if my advice solved your problem, please mark my answer as helpfull.. thanks